# how to translate "请优先发给我，抄送其他人" in an email?

Tags: translation

> 请优先发给我，抄送其他人

Is it: "please reply to me and cc others"?

Or does 优先 express the priority, the emergency of the issue and that translation should be: "please reply to me ASAP, and keep others in the loop"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`优先` expresses priority/precedence/privilege, but not urgency.

In this specific sentence it feels redundant to me. I think the person was trying to emphasize that he/she should be the only one on the TO line and others on CC line are FYI (for your information) only.

Comment: In email we say "cc" (carbon copy) to others...

Comment: @phoeagon I know. I am trying to explain the connotation of 优先 here, but now I see how the answer could be confusing in that regard. I'll update it. Thanks.